# useEffect dependency cause an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, infinite

```js
function Reply({ id, user }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [replyText, setReplyText] = useState("");
  
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const response = await _axios.get("/reply/" + id);
      setData(response.data);
    }
    fetchData();   
  }, [data]);   <---- ** problem ** with data(dependency),
                                    infinite request(call) fetchData()
  
  ...
  }
```

what's the reason for infinite loop if there's a dependency.
as far as i know, when dependency(data) change, re-render.
but useEffect keep asking for data(axios.get(~~)).
if i leave a comment, i can see normally the latest comments, but the network tab(in develop tools) keeps asking for data(304 Not Modified, under image)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's an infinite loop because that code says "If `data` changes, request information from the server and change `data`." The second half of that changes `data`, which triggers the first half again.

You're not using `data` in the callback, so it shouldn't be a dependency. Just remove it:

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
        const response = await _axios.get("/reply/" + id);
        setData(response.data);
    }
    fetchData();   
}, []);
// ^^−−−−−−−−−− don't put `data` here
```

That gives you a blank dependency array, which will run the effect only when the component first mounts. (If you want to run it again after mount, use a different state member for that, or define `fetchData` outside the effect and use it both in the effect and at the other time you want to fetch data.)

---

Side note: Nothing in your code is handling rejections from your `fetchData` function, which will cause "unhandled rejection" errors. You'll want to hook up a rejection handler to report or suppress the error.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `setData` after the response which causes the data to change and hence the `useEffect(() => {<>your code<>} ,[data])` to fire again.

use `useEffect(() => {<>your code<>},[])` if you want to execute the AJAX call only once after component mounting

or

use `useEffect(() => {<>your code<>})` without the dependency if you want to execute the AJAX call after the component mount and after every update

Comment: Does that mean having a `state` for things like `network requests`, it is better to just avoid using `useEffect` and just use individual actions such as `useCallback` or `useMemo`? The React documentation makes it seem like putting dependencies is good practice

Answer (score 1):

Dependencies argument of `useEffect` is `useEffect(callback, dependencies)`

Let's explore side effects and runs:

**Not provided: the side-effect runs after every rendering.**

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Runs after EVERY rendering
  });  
}
```

**An empty array []: the side-effect runs once after the initial rendering.**

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
  useEffect(() => {
    // Runs ONCE after initial rendering
  }, []);
}
```

**Has props or state values `[prop1, prop2, ..., state1, state2]`: the side-effect runs only when any dependency value changes.**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

function MyComponent({ prop }) {
  const [state, setState] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
    // Runs ONCE after initial rendering
    // and after every rendering ONLY IF `prop` or `state` changes
  }, [prop, state]);
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. It is just merely explaining what useEffect does with the dependencies. The questions is WHY does it cause an infinite loop. Hate to be a grinch, but searching for answers and always wasting time reading answers like this is kind of getting stale.